# How can I only install dependencies for a particular package managed by `nx`

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I have a monorepo managed by `nx`. And I use `yarn install` to install dependencies. I found when I run `yarn install` under one package folder, it installs dependencies from other packages.

```
packages/is-event/package.json
packages/is-odd/package.json
package.json
node_modules
```

Above is my project folder structure, I have one dependency in `is-odd` package, when I run `yarn install` in `is-even` package, the dependency from `is-odd` was downloaded and saved in the root level `node_modules` folder. How can I avoid downloading other packages' dependencies?

I have removed the `node_modules` folder before running `yarn install` in `is-odd` folder.